# Combine multiple replace commands

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string and I want to clean it, for that I am using multiple replace commands.

Is there a better way to do it?

```
a = '[[<Package 9.00x6.00x5.60>, <Package 8.75x6.60x5.60>]]'

a.replace("[<Package ","").replace(">]","").replace("<Package ","").replace(">","")
```

Result:

```
'[9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the following approach:

```
import re

a = '[[<Package 9.00x6.00x5.60>, <Package 8.75x6.60x5.60>]]'
output = '[' + ''.join(re.split('[><[\]]|Package ',a)) + ']'
print(output)
```

where you split your string in a list using the delimiters: `>`, `<`, `]`, `[`, `Package` then you concatenate the result in a string and add the outer brackets.

**output:**

```
[9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `re.sub`:

```
a = '[[<Package 9.00x6.00x5.60>, <Package 8.75x6.60x5.60>]]'
output = re.sub(r'<Package ([^>]+)>', r'\1', a)
# remove outer [] brackets
output = output[1:-1]
print(output)

[9.00x6.00x5.60, 8.75x6.60x5.60]
```